# How can I easily access a list of questions I have asked in order of newest created first?

Tags: support, profile-page

How can I easily access a list of questions I have asked in order of newest created first? The most confusing part about navigating the stack exchange sites is that I can't just go to a list of the questions that I have asked. I have to hunt around in all these subsections of the site just to get to my own questions and answers. Either I am lost of a bit of interface improvement is needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On your profile page, under the `Questions` tab, click `Newest`:

[image: newest]

Comment: I am compelled to upvote the only answer with freehand circles.

Comment: Thanks, would be nice if this was more obvious. There already is a "questions" tab, which is very prominent, but it shows all the questions on the site. When I view my profile I'd like easy access to my own questions...

Comment: When you view your profile, you have.

Comment: Right, I notice it now, in the summary section.

Answer (score 2):

Visit the [questions tab of your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/407615/victor-s?tab=questions&sort=newest) or perform a [search for your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a407615%20is%3aquestion), sorted newest to oldest.

You can get a record of everything you've posted by going to your profile, which can be accessed by clicking your user name at the top of any page.

Additionally, an aggregate view of all questions and answers you've posted across the Stack Exchange network, sorted by post date in descending order, is available on [your network profile activity tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/176740/victor-s?tab=activity).

Answer (score 0):

Just use your [profile page's questions tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/407615/victor-s?tab=questions).

You can sort them by votes, last activity date, creation date, and views.